# Is there a way to add a new column with default based on existing column without rewrite?

Tags: postgresql

So I need to add a new column to an existing table. This column should have a default value that needs to be calculated based on existing column (Let's say for example that we have **Id** column and default function for new column is **NewColumn = Id + 1**).
Considering that table is very large, it is necessary that table won't be rewritten.
I know that I can use generated columns or after insert trigger but it seems that it will cause table rewrite. Is it possible to do what I need without a rewrite?

Comment: Better create a view instead. It will be much simpler and faster.

Comment: You cannot use column reference in a `default` expression. `Generated always` rewrites the whole table. A trigger would do this without accessing existing data but I'd suggest creating a view.

Comment: In short: no, you cannot.